# Merge implementation with semaphores

Tags: c, merge, semaphore

I'm trying to implement merge sort with semaphores and I have some troubles making my code running:

```
sem_t *sem;
pthread_t *t;

void *parallel_merge_sort(void *thread_id)
{
int a = *((int *) thread_id);
printf("%d. in sort\n",a);
fflush(stdout);
sem_post(&(sem[a]));
if(a % 2)
    sem_wait(&(sem[a-1]));
else
    sem_wait(&(sem[a+1]));

printf("%d. out sort\n",a);
fflush(stdout);
}

void main()
{
int P = 2,i;    

t = calloc(P,sizeof(pthread_t));
sem = calloc(P,sizeof(sem_t));

printf("threads created\n");
fflush(stdout);

for(i=0;i<P;i++)    
    pthread_create(&(t[i]),NULL,(void*) &parallel_merge_sort,(void *) &i);

for(i=0;i<P;i++)
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL);

    printf("threads end\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

This code produces output like the following one:

```
threads created    
0. in sort       
0. in sort
```

After this, it doesn't continue to run and wait.

What can the problem be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee that a new thread starts immediately. This means that you can't use a pointer to the index as the variable may change before the thread starts.

In this case it seems that the threads doesn't start until the main thread have entered the second loop, in which the variable `i` is reset to zero, so both threads will have the same index, making both threads to try to wait on the same semaphore.

You can bypass this by using a "hack" and pass `i` directly as the pointer:

```
pthread_create(&(t[i]),NULL,(void*) &parallel_merge_sort,(void *) i);
```

And in the thread function do:

```
int a = (int) thread_id;
```